# Misunderstanding the usage of := in Go

Tags: go

I was reading [this doc](https://gobyexample.com/variables) and saw the following fragment:

> The := syntax is shorthand for declaring and initializing a variable, e.g. for var f string = "short" in this case.

```
f := "short"
fmt.Println(f)
```

The point is: is it only for strings? Or is it dymanic enough to understand what datatype should it store?

And plus: isn't it the same of `var f = "short"`?

Comment: It's not dynamic, it's "type inference"

Comment: I would suggest you to bookmark language specs. Its a good place to look into when you have questions like this : https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations :)

Comment: @Omie thank you about the specs referencing. :D

Comment: I just can't understand why the downvotes. Could someone explain them to me?

Comment: Note that this kind of 'type inference' doesn't actually require any sort of smartness from the compiler - the expression on the right obviously already has a well defined type. 'inferring' the type of the variable basically just means copying the type from the rhs to the lhs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it infers the obvious type(s) returned by the expression on the right side.

The [specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) gives those examples :

```
i, j := 0, 10
f := func() int { return 7 }
ch := make(chan int)
r, w := os.Pipe(fd)  // os.Pipe() returns two values
_, y, _ := coord(p)  // coord() returns three values; only interested in y coordinate
```

Note that it's not dynamic : everything happens at compile time, the type(s) being given by the right part expression.